# How to add a bootstrap glyphicons in a flask template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm still new to flask... I want to add a glyphicon in my flask template, but it does not appear...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>breakdiet</title>

    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/essentials.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="logo">breakdiet</h1>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using **Bootstrap 4**, and this one don't come with an **ICONS** library. Glyphicons was part of **Bootstrap 3** and was dropped now, thats why you don't see anything. You can include **font-awesome** library (for example) if you want an icon library. Read more on next links:

[Icons On Boostrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/extend/icons/)

[Font Awesome Library](https://fontawesome.com/)

You can see an example of use on the next snippet. Also note you include libraries on wrong order previously, **Proppet** and **JQuery** should be include before **Bootstrap**.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div>You can see an icon below:</div>
<div><i class="fas fa-3x fa-ghost"></i></div>
```